# Search functionality works on first page but when I move to page 2 or page 3 through pagination then Search did not work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a crud operation page. When I am searching for any data from page 1  then the search functionality works very well but when I am going to another page using pagination button and after that when I am going to search something then it will returns me a empty result. can anyone figure it out , what i am doing wrong or where I can make changes?

```
import Wrapper from '../Helpers/Wrapper';
import './Users.css';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "../Layout/Modal";
import Button from '../UI/Button';
import axios from "axios";
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

const Users = () => {

const searchRef = useRef();

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [editUser, setEditUser] = useState([]);
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState();
const [title, setTitle] = useState("Add a new User");

const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
const [apid, setApid] = useState(null);

// The ids of users who are removed from the list
const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
const [isCheckAll, setIsCheckAll] = useState(false);

const getApiData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://geektrust.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/adminui-problem/members.json');
    const data = res.data;
    setApid(data);
    const postData = data.slice(offset, offset + perPage);
    setUsers(postData);
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / perPage))
}
useEffect(() => {
    getApiData();
}, [offset]);
const deleteRecord = userId => {
    const newUsersList = [...users];
    const index = users.findIndex(user => user.id === userId);
    newUsersList.splice(index, 1);
    setUsers(newUsersList);
};
const errorHandler = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
};
const addUsermodal = () => {
    setOpenModal(true);
};
const onCheckHandler = userRecord => {
    const filtereduser = users.findIndex(record => record.id === userRecord.id);
    if (filtereduser != -1) {
        users[filtereduser] = userRecord;
    } else {
        const newUsersList = [userRecord, ...users];
        setUsers(newUsersList);
    }
}
const editRecord = (record) => {
    setEditUser(record);
    setOpenModal(true);
    setTitle('Update User');
};
const searchList = () => {
    const enteredSearchData = searchRef.current.value;
    setSearchValue(enteredSearchData);
};
const handlePageClick = async (e) => {
    const selectedPage = (e.selected * 10) % apid.length;
    setOffset(selectedPage);
};
const selectUserRecord = event => {
    const selectedId = event.target.value;
    if (ids.includes(selectedId)) {
        const newIds = ids.filter((id) => id !== selectedId);
        setIds(newIds);
    } else {
        const newIds = [...ids];
        newIds.push(selectedId);
        setIds(newIds);
    }
};
const removeSelected = event => {
    const remainingUser = users.filter(
        user => !ids.includes(user.id)
    )
    setUsers(remainingUser);
};
const selectAllVisibleUserRecord = event => {
    setIsCheckAll(!isCheckAll);
    const postData = users.slice(offset, offset + perPage);
    setIds(postData.map(li => li.id));
    getApiData();
    if (isCheckAll) {
        setIds([]);
    }
};

const btnMT = {
    marginTop: '20px'
}
return (
    <Wrapper>
        {openModal && (<Modal
            title={title}
            editUser={editUser}
            onConfirm={errorHandler}
            oncheck={onCheckHandler}
        />)}
        <div className="panelWrapper">
            <h1>Users</h1>
            <div className="addUsers" onClick={addUsermodal}>
                <img src="./plus.svg" alt="add" />
                <span>Add new User</span>
            </div>
            <div className="searchData">
                <div className="searchBox">
                    <label htmlFor="search">Search</label>
                    <input
                        id="search"
                        type="text"
                        ref={searchRef}
                    />
                </div>
                <Button type={'button'} onClick={searchList}>Search</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="usersList">
                <div className="tableWrapper">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <input
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        name="selectAll"
                                        id="selectAll"
                                        onChange={selectAllVisibleUserRecord}
                                    />
                                </th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {users.filter(data => {
                                if (searchValue === '' || searchValue === undefined) {
                                    return data;
                                } else if (data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                                    return data;
                                } else if (data.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                                    return data;
                                } else if (data.role.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                                    return data;
                                }
                            }).map((listdata) => (
                                <tr key={listdata.id} className={ids.includes(listdata.id) ? 'checked' : ''}>
                                    <td>
                                        <input
                                            id={`custom-checkbox-${listdata.id}`}
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value={listdata.id}
                                            name={listdata.name}
                                            onChange={selectUserRecord}
                                            checked={ids.includes(listdata.id) ? true : false}
                                        />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{listdata.id}</td>
                                    <td>{listdata.name}</td>
                                    <td>{listdata.email}</td>
                                    <td>{listdata.role}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="./edit.svg" alt="edit" onClick={event => editRecord(listdata)} />
                                        <img src="./delete.svg" alt="Delete" onClick={event => deleteRecord(listdata.id)} />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style={btnMT}>
                    <Button type={'button'} onClick={removeSelected}>Delete Selected</Button>
                </div>
                <ReactPaginate
                    previousLabel={"prev"}
                    nextLabel={"next"}
                    breakLabel={"..."}
                    breakClassName={"break-me"}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                    activeClassName={"active"} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </Wrapper>
);
```

}

export default Users;

Comment: it's working as you expected pls check-in demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-raman-gb00ne?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: search is working when the first page is selected in Pagination.  you can change first the page from pagination, move to page 2 or any other page then have to search something, then search is not working. that is the issue.